# What magical tomes does Dr. Strange possess?

Tags: marvel, doctor-strange

There are several tomes of magic referenced in Dr. Strange, that he utilizes at various points along his journeys. The most notable being:

- [Book of Vishanti](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_the_Vishanti)
- [Darkhold/Book of Sins](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Darkhold)
- [Book of Cagliostro](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Cagliostro)
- Blood Bible

Ignoring his substantial inventory of magical artifacts (Eye of Agamotto, etc), what is the complete list of magical tomes known to be in the possession of Dr. Strange?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Marvel Wiki, which is admittedly missing sources for some of the listings, the full list of tomes in the [Mystical Library of the Sanctum Sanctorum](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sanctum_Sanctorum#Points_of_Interest) is:

- [Book of Cagliostro](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Cagliostro)
- [Book of Demonicus](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Demonicus)
- [Book of Eibon](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Eibon)
- [Book of Fire](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Fire)
- [Book of Morphesti](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Morphesti)
- [Book of Shataki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Shataki)
- [Book of the Vishanti](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_the_Vishanti)
- [Darkhold](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Darkhold)
- [Grimorium Verum](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Grimorium_Verum)
- [Kartkuthi](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Kartkuthi)
- [Necronomicon](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Necronomicon)
- [Scroll of Melsalam](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Scroll_of_Melsalam)
- [Scrolls of Watoomb](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolls_of_Watoomb)
- [Oral Scrolls of Tooli](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Oral_Scrolls_of_Tooli)
- Unpublished manuscript by the occultist [Dion Fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dion_Fortune)
- Diary of Kenneth Ward
- Grimoire of Watoomb
- Scroll of Eternity
- Tome of Oshtur

Comment: Can you provide a more accurate source rather than just stating it’s missing sources?